# Get only last traceback without using raise from None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, traceback

I have a common situation in my projects, where I use custom Exceptions to wrap built in exception scenarios, like:

```
# meaningless here but in other situations its useful...
try:
   5/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
   raise MyCustomException(msg=str(e))
```

along with a universal exception handler that looks like this:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)   # this decorator is flask related - ignore it
def handle_error(error):
    if isinstance(error, MyCustomException):
        # some code
        # I only want MyCustomException traceback
    else:
        # some other code    
        exc_stack = traceback.format_exc(limit=5)
```

The known issue here is that I get both exception tracebacks, whereas in if-case I want only the last one.

**There are two solutions in this problem as far as I know.**

First workaround (use `from None`):

```
try:
   5/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
   raise MyCustomException(msg=str(e)) from None   # python3
```

Second workaround (call the traceback before raising the second exception)

```
try:
    5/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
   tracb = traceback.format_exc(limit=5)
   raise MyCustomException(msg=str(e), tracb_msg=tracb)
```

No need to call `traceback.format_exc()` in exception handler, just use the `tracb_msg` passed to the instance. Obviously first workaround is simpler.

**My Problem:**

Both of these approaches re-appear (repeating code/trick) dozens of times inside the code, **every time** I raise `MyCustomException`. Has anyone come up with a trick to handle this **once** inside the handler function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `__suppress_context__` attribute to disable context printing.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html), using `raise MyCustomException(foo) from bar` sets `__cause__` to `bar`, and `__context__` to the original exception (the implicitly chained exception).

> An implicitly chained exception in `__context__` is shown only if `__cause__` is None and `__suppress_context__` is false.

Here's an example:

```
# Declare an exception that never shows context.


class MyCustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__suppress_context__ = True

try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    raise MyCustomException(str(e))
```

Here's the output I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise MyCustomException(str(e))
MyCustomException: division by zero
```

Here's the output if I set `__suppress_context__` to `False`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 10, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise MyCustomException(str(e))
MyCustomException: division by zero
```

Comment: Could you explain this line: `d = list(reversed(sorted(dir(e))))`. Actually d isn't used at all probably, but I wondered if its something we could use it somehow

Comment: Sorry, @chefarov, that was just a debugging statement I used to learn what attributes were available on the exception. I left it in by accident.

Comment: Looks like it's better to use an instance attribute than a class attribute, @chefarov. The default error handler's stack trace seems to ignore the class attribute. I switched my example.